# How do I update a JLabel in a JPanel?

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

I am having trouble getting the image on my JLabel to update in the JPanel. I do not see what the problem is. I have tried removing the existing JLabel and adding a new one to the JPanel but that doesn't work. Here is the code I am trying to get the animaiton to work on. My key listener works fine so I am sure there is some problem in this class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Character extends JPanel{
  //Constructs array that holds running frames
  static ImageIcon running[] = new ImageIcon[19];
  static int i = 0;
  //Contstructs label that holds the current image frame
  static JLabel characterLabel = new JLabel();
  //Creates imageicon to be returned to the character and stored in characterLabel
  static ImageIcon character = new ImageIcon();

  Timer runningTimer = new Timer(300, new RunningListener());



  public Character() {

    running[0] = new ImageIcon("running 1.png");
    running[1] = new ImageIcon("running 2.png");
    running[2] = new ImageIcon("running 3.png");
    running[3] = new ImageIcon("running 4.png");
    running[4] = new ImageIcon("running 5.png");
    running[5] = new ImageIcon("running 6.png");
    running[6] = new ImageIcon("running 7.png");
    running[7] = new ImageIcon("running 8.png");
    running[8] = new ImageIcon("running 9.png");
    running[9] = new ImageIcon("running 10.png");
    running[10] = new ImageIcon("running 11.png");
    running[11] = new ImageIcon("running 12.png");
    running[12] = new ImageIcon("running 13.png");
    running[13] = new ImageIcon("running 14.png");
    running[14] = new ImageIcon("running 15.png");
    running[15] = new ImageIcon("running 16.png");
    running[16] = new ImageIcon("running 17.png");
    running[17] = new ImageIcon("running 18.png");
    running[18] = new ImageIcon("running 19.png");
    characterLabel.setIcon(running[0]);
    this.add(characterLabel);
  }

  private void refreshCharacter(){
     this.remove(characterLabel);
    characterLabel.setIcon(running[i]);
    this.add(characterLabel);
    i++;
    if (i > 18){
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  private class RunningListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      refreshCharacter();
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose that this JPanel may be the problem aswell but I doubt it:

```
import javax.swing.*;

//Panel that manages the game
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{


  //Adds stuff to GamePanel to send to Frame
  public GamePanel(){

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput());
    this.add(new Character()); 
  }
}
```

Here is the key listener:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

//Listens for key actions
public class KeyInput implements KeyListener{

  //Constructs character
  Character c = new Character();

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    int key = evt.getKeyCode();
    //When the right key is pressed, start the timer that starts the running animation
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
      c.runningTimer.start();
    }
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt){
    int key = evt.getKeyCode();
    //When the right key is released, the timer that starts the running animation is stopped
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
   c.runningTimer.stop();
    }
  }

  //There is no use for this... it just has to be there
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt){
  }
}
```

and here is the frame:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Frame{

  //Creates window and calls to GamePanel
  public static void main (String[]args){
    GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Game");

    window.add(gamePanel);
    window.setLocation(50,50);
    window.setSize(1000,650);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    window.setVisible(true);
    gamePanel.requestFocus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to change a displayed image, if you can avoid it, don't remove JLabels or components, but rather swap a JLabel's Icon. If you're not trying to change an image, but do something different, then please give us more detail on your desired behavior, since all you tell us is that you're trying "animation", and that's somewhat broad.

e.g.,

```
private void refreshCharacter() {
   i++;
   i %= running.length;
   characterLabel.setIcon(running[i]);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to dynamically change the image that i am adding to the  character JPanel so it keeps updating to the next frame of the animation. What do you think would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: @RoryNitti: for example, see change to answer.

Comment: @RoryNitti: also note that I prefer Key Bindings to KeyListeners in this situation.